# How to calculate distinct element and puth distint values in a particular array

Tags: python, arrays

Column is a array having around 10000 values which include repetitive values also. I want a array `darray` which should include only distinct values without repetition. I was trying to do by this code. But length of `darray` is coming out as 0. Some problem with the break statements. With using break I want to come out of inner two loops but not the third loop. Help me out.

```
darray=[]
m=0

for d in range(0,length):
    f=0
    for r in range(d,length):
        if f==1:
            break
        for l in range(0,m):
            if column[r] == darray[l]:
                f=1
                break
            elif column[d] == column[r]:
                darray.append(column[d])
                m+=1
                f=1
                break


lent = len(darray)     
print lent;
```

Comment: Your code is indented wrong. Indenting is very important in Python, please fix otherwise noone can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If ordering in the resulting array is not relevant, you can just use a set:

```
lent=set(column)
```

(or `list(set(column))` if you need the result to actually be a list)

Otherwise, you can use a set as auxiliary data structure to quickly see if the new array already has an element.

```
s=set()
lent=[] 
for v in column:
    if v not in s:
        lent.append(v) 
        s.add(v)
```

Both of these are O(n log n), compared to the O(n^2) (or worse) of the naive solution.

Comment: problem is length of darray is coming 0. but according to the code it should not come